# AngularJS: how to "create" controller in unit test, and why scope is not defined?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

everywhere in application my company created we used this example of how to create a controller :

```
app.myFunnyController = function($scope.....){}
```

but i see that everywhere in test people are using this way of creating controllers:

```
app.controller('myFunnyController', function ($scope) {
}
```

And i can see that when i am creating my test and using app.myFunnyController declaration:

```
'use strict';
describe('publicCtrl', function(){
 beforeEach(module('app')); 
    it("should be true", inject(function($controller){
       var scope = {},
        ctrl = $controller('myFunnyController', {$scope : scope});
       expect(scope.data).toBe("test2");

    }));
})
```

I getting an error of myFunnyController is not a function. If i using the second type of declaration, everything works fine. Why does this happend?

An other problem is that i am getting error:  scope is not defined. 
I am new to Karma and Unit testing for front end, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please further specify your second issue in a separate question. I can't see any obvious reason why scope should not be defined, so we may need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, the second syntax (`app.controller(...)`) registers the controller function on the module. The first syntax just adds the controller function as an attribute of the module. `app.controller` does a bit more magic under the hood so that when you call `$controller('myFunnyController, ...)` in your test, the module knows about the controller and can run it. This is the recommended way to define controllers according to the [angular controllers guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object).